# Modify CSV rows before importing with tap and yield

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I am working on a feature on an open source project.
At some point a CSV file is imported and I create an array out of it to pass it in a new object. 
After

```
CSV.open(path, 'rb', opts)
```

this is used to get the block of code

```
.tap { |c| yield c if block_given? }
```

My question is, how to get access to the data imported?
After `tap` there is a method sequence.

Edit:
I don't want to re-write it I want to test it. I know I am supposed to use tap to modify the data, but I don't know how to do that as I don't see any way to reference the data of the CSV

Comment: You would like to access the data after the array is created or before it? Could you specify at what point you want to get access to that data and what exactly you would like to do?

Comment: I'd like to get access to the data before the array is created. At least that's what I'm supposed to do, the code was already there on this open source project and I try to test it. After the tap method I use the `.to_a` to make an array. The goal is to modify what I want before I import it into the array. That array is temporary, it's just used as an input to a new Object.

Comment: Can't you modify that data by passing a block to  `#tap`?

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do. But how do I refer to the data?

Comment: Take a look at your earlier post. `block { |x| puts "evens: #{x.inspect}"}` If you sent block like that, `x` would be the data. To be more precise `yield c` sends `c` (your data) to your new block, where `x` (in a new block) would become the `c` (your data).

Comment: Can you write an answer, explaining it more please? Sorry for being such a noob, I'm not very familiar with file manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not really have anything to do with file manipulation at this point. It's more about understanding how `#tap` and blocks work.

```
def block
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].tap { |array| yield array if block_given?}
end
block { |array| array.each{ |element| puts element } }
```

The output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

In a method `block`, an array `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` is initialized, afterwards we `tap` into that array, which makes that array available in the `tap`'s block.

In the example above, when `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` is passed to `tap` it is available in `array` variable, which is specified like this: `|array|`. Then `array` is yield to the block `if block_given?`. That means that in the new block `|array|` contains `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` too. So in that new block that you pass to `tap`, you can modify that array, or just output it like I did.

Comment: Still nothing. I don't get why it doesn't work. 
`.from_csv ('spec/fixtures/block_given_example.csv') {|x| x.each{|elem| puts elem}}`

Comment: What is the output?

Comment: No output at all. The expected input is there, the test passes but I don't see printed. I will try something else when I get home and report back, I'm really grateful for your help. :)

Comment: Show me then the code for that test and we will try to debug it together.

Comment: Got it. For some reason, adding `&block` as a parameter to the method my test calls fixed the issue of nothing showing. Now I have another one. Passing a simple block like `{|x| x.each{|row| row.each{|elem| puts elem}}}` doesn't actually put the data into an array. So I'm left with a var pointing to an empty array.

Comment: What do you mean by put the data into an array? Your block displays every elem of every row at the moment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139158/discussion-between-dinos-12345-and-diodonhystrix).